# Are omissions like "he has a Facebook [account]" an ellipsis of the modern age, or has this always been going on?

Tags: history, ellipses

Some English speakers omit "account" in conversational speech when referring to their membership in an online service. For example:

- "Here's a link to my Tumblr."
- "I took a break for a while, but I have a Facebook again."

In both cases the word "account" seems to be elided, and "a Tumblr" or "a Facebook" is used as a stand-in to mean "an account or presence with that online service".

The nearest similar example I can think of that comes to mind is something like "I own a Chevy", where it is understood that you mean a *car* (rather than, say, a Chevrolet-branded *tire*, or *engine*, et cetera). The omission feels more natural here, whereas some people bristle at the above examples with online services.

Are there recurring historical examples where a similar effect has occurred with other entities, or is this otherwise a feature of the modern age? Is there a name for this kind of abbreviation effect?

Comment: Been going on forever. "Adjective" used to mean "adjective noun" as contrasted with "substantive noun", for instance. If you have a common word with too many syllables, shorten it in context and everybody understands. Do it long enough and it becomes a new word.

Comment: It's especially common with brand names. In some cases, it becomes so common that we forget that the word is actually a trademark, and we say it has "genericized". This happened to frigidaire, linoleum, cellophane, and kleenex, for example.

Comment: One of the nastier proofs that is has been going on is something like:
He is taller than I [am].
The 'am' is forgotten and it seems to be becoming:
He is taller than me.

Comment: @Barmar: Funnily enough, some eponymous names vary from region to region. E.g. if I were to ask for a bic, an American would give me a lighter, but a Flemishman would give me a ballpoint pen. Same company that makes both products, it's not just coincidentally the name eponymous name.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235310/what-is-the-concept-of-using-an-adjective-instead-of-adjectivenoun-called ?

Comment: It should be pointed out that many people probably view their Facebook account as their Face Book.  That is, to them the account is called a "Facebook".  It only feels "unnatural" to you because you're an old fart and can remember when there was no Facebook.

Comment: Bit of a nit pick, but do people really say *a* Facebook?  I've only ever heard 'I'm *on* Facebook' or 'I've stopped (being on) Facebook'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From time immemorial, whenever the specific descriptor becomes common or dominant enough, the more general descriptor can be elided without confusion:

> 21st century Facebook [account]
>   20th century *[Jello](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=jello&searchmode=none)* [gelatin]
>   19th century *[Levi](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=levi&searchmode=none)* [jean]s
>   18th century *[Fahrenheit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fahrenheit&searchmode=none)* [scale]
>   17th century *[mansard](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mansard&searchmode=none)* 
>   [roof]
>   16th century
>   *[china](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=china&searchmode=none)* [dishes]

Answer (score 1):

This particular set of examples are due to brand culture. Brand culture is fairly new (mostly because brands as we know them didn't exist in the past and the presence of many makers made the use of brand names unfeasible), though not exactly *brand* new. Example: the swords made by Gorō Masamune, c.1264–1343 AD, were known by his name and an indicator of which sword it was, i.e. the Fudo Masamune, a sword with an engraving of Fudo Myu-o on it, without references to the item being a sword, as that was already understood.

The key to such ellipses appears to be when a brand takes over a large market share (and thus takes the place of the product in the public eye, as with Coke being used in parts of the US to mean any sort of soda pop), or particularly great qualities inherent in a single brand.

http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2011/10/how-brands-were-born-a-brief-history-of-modern-marketing/246012/

Comment: I think there's definitely something to the idea of it being related to brand culture, but I'm not sure that Coke example is convincing. While Facebook is definitely very popular, I don't think people are using "Facebook" in a substitutional manner -- that is, I don't observe people conflating Facebook with related services like, say, Twitter or Instagram.

Comment: Facebook overtook the personal profile market, overcoming MySpace, Friendster, (non-professional use of)LinkedIn, etc. It's so huge that there's no question of what it is; it has something like 5% of the world population on it.

Comment: Twitter and Instagram differ from Facebook in that they are dedicated messages and pictures platforms (and perform better to this end). They are profiles in the technical sense, but one can't just look at what someone says and what pictures they take and presume they know the person.  In that way, they're more complementary goods than substitutes.  That said, this brings up a point; when have you heard someone ask if you have a Flickr or a Photobucket, sans an indicator of what they are, since Instagram?